# assigning values to elements in nested zend sub forms

Tags: php, jquery, zend-form, zendx, zend-form-sub-form

I have a 3 tier form structure.

There's a main form, frmMain (which acts more like a container form) which has subforms e.g **frmSubFacts**. And these sub forms such as **frmSubFacts** have subforms; for example: **frmTabSubCountry**. The innermost subform contains the form elements such as text fields. These are grouped using the setBelongsTo method at the form level.

The code uses ZendX_JQuery to render these forms across 2 tab lines such that
**frmSubFacts** and other outer sub forms are within the top tabs, and based on user selection, the sub-subforms (such as **frmTabSubCountry**) are displayed along a second inner tab line.

The form renders well. The only problem is programmatically setting values to the fields/elements within the innermost sub forms.

The element fields names are rendered based on their hierarchy and relationship such that a text box name could be: **Facts[Country][county_name]**.

However, how do I get to assign a value to this field? I have tried the following options:

```
$arrFormData['Facts[Country][county_name]'] = 'Singapore';

$Form->populate(array('Facts'=> 
        array('Country'=> array('country_name'=> 'Singapore'))));

$form->Facts->Country->country_name->setValue('Singapore');

$form->getSubForm('Facts')
                 ->getSubForm('Country')
                     ->getElement('country_name')->setValue('Singapore');
```

Although the application renders well and POST actions are as expected, the last line to get Subforms fails after getting the 'Facts' subform. Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

Check if this helps:

```
$this->element->Facts->Country->country_name->setValue('Singapore');
```